# Proper way of handling network requests for bad connections?

Tags: android, http, networking, retrofit2

This should be a generic problem but till now I haven't heard or read about it anywhere.

So the problem is that when we send a network request(`POST` requests are critical) from mobile app to server, sometimes user get disconnected from internet before receiving a response and `retrofit`(android networking library) respond with connection error, although request was sent to server. So server created a new entry for that request but user was unaware of this.

And after seeing a connection error user tries to create same entry again and we end up having duplicate entries.

What are the possible solutions for this? Though our app is built on Android this problem should be generic and be known to many developers.

We are disabling button in app till response is received from server, so clicking button twice in quick succession is not the problem.

> What we are thinking

- Get a UUID from server for any new request and send UUID with each request, so that server discard a UUID once used.

Comment: I think this problem can be tackled from the backend perspective where if the backend finds out that a duplicate request has arrived, it would send back an error notifying android developer that the request has already been registered at the backend side

Comment: That's what we were thinking to do by sending UUID from backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can Extend Time out limit in Retrofit for slow Connection in Your Application Class (Where you initialize **OkHttpClient**) Put there your Connection time out Limit.

```
// OkHttpClient client = httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

//use this client object

     OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .readTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(650, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();
```

Comment: Time out is not the problem and it's given 10sec already which more than required. Problem is not slow connection rather bad connection.